# how does spring security order multiple SecurityFilterChains?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

i have two SecurityFilterChains one for any, another which bypasses httpbasic for some urls. rn, its workings as expected. but i am skeptical of the ordering. how does spring security order these chains. since spring docs says the first chain that matches will handle the request. in this case if any matches first it will handle the request causing issues.

also, i think this is better than setting ignoreFailure in BasicFilter, which i couldn't figure out anyways.

Answer (score 2):

It will check the `SecurityFilterChain` one by one according to the priority which can be defined by the `@Order` likes :

```java
@Bean
@Order(1)                                                        
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain1(HttpSecurity http){
        
}

@Bean
@Order(2)                                                        
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain2(HttpSecurity http){
        
}
```

Smaller order value has higher priority which will be checked first (i.e check securityFilterChain1 first in this example).

Once a `SecurityFilterChain` is matched with the request , it will stop checking the rest filter chain. So you are right that if you configure the `securityFilterChain1` to match for all request , `securityFilterChain2` basically is useless as it will never be invoked. So you have to pay attention to the ordering , the one that with more specific matching URL should has higher priority than the general one.

It just like catching an exception in Java which we need to catch a more specific exception before the general one.

Comment: How does Spring Security decides which FilterChain to call first in case, we don't apply `@Order` annotation? Is there a rule or is it completely unpredictable?

Comment: From the docs. (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/annotation-config/autowired.html) , if you do not apply `@Order` , the order is the same as the order of the bean definition defined registered in the spring container. Not sure how does it works to be honest. So the advice if you have multiple `SecurityFilterChain` , define the explicit order to make it predictable.

Comment: @KenChan can you add docs link for this. i had an idea it has to do something with `@Order` but those eg. were with  WebMvcConfigurer. so i was not certain. also, how does it work without `@Order`. does bean declared before/top gets picked by spring before?